# Is service running all the time bad?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-background, battery-saver

I am trying to learn about service and BroadCastReceiver.
Code below is a service which runs all the time in the background.  The problem is I don't know how it would affect the battery consumption.

My goal is to detect the screen on and off, so I need a running service in the background when the app is close or open...

Is it going to drain a lot of battery?
Can you please explain it?

Thank you

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private BroadcastReceiver mScreenOnOffReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver OnOffBroadcastReceiver;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private Notification barNotif;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // here to show that your service is running foreground     
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, WidgetBroadCastReceiver.class);       
        PendingIntent pbIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , bIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        NotificationCompat.Builder bBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("STICKY")
                    .setContentText("Sub Title")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pbIntent);
        barNotif = bBuilder.build();
        this.startForeground(1, barNotif);

    // here the body of your service where you can arrange your reminders and send alerts

     Thread mThread = new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         // Register the ScreenOnOffReceiver.java  
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mScreenOnOffReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mScreenOnOffReceiver, filter);

        // initialize and register mScreenOnOffReceiver (no need the BroadcastReceiver class)
        OnOffBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                    Log.e("", "SERVICE Screen is: " +  "turned OFF.....");
                } 
           else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    Log.e("", "SERVICE Screen is: " +  "turned ON......");
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(OnOffBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(filter));       
         }
     };

     mThread.start();   

    return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service has Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        unregisterReceiver(mScreenOnOffReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(OnOffBroadcastReceiver);
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Wilfred Hughes.  I very appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example, the service didn't do some operations (intensive computing, network request etc.) that consume battery. So personally I think it is not very obviously that your service will consume a lot of battery. But the service is kept after it's started, which means your app will take more memory footprint. In some way, I think large memory app will take more system's battery, the system need to do more extra work to keep the overall performance in a good state, these extra work need CPU, IO and memory's computing and read/write cycle that consume the battery.

Your didn't start a new thread in your service, which means all the work of your service will run on main thread. In this way, it will cause `ANR` with high possibility if you do long time operation which blocks UI. In your example, you just start notification and register broadcast receiver, your app run smoothly and didn't complain `ANR` because these two operation finish very soon. But you should be aware that.

Personally it's might be better if you put your `BroadcastReceiver` to `AndroidManifest.xml`, it's not very usual like the way you did.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  I edited and added the new thread in my question.  Can you please check and see if I run the service in a new thread correctly?  Thank you!

Comment: In you example, it's not necessary to start new thread, you didn't do long time operation in you code. Check the [implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) of `IntentService` if you want to add thread support in your service. Actually most of time you should use `IntentService`, as the official android document recommend.